# W3C validation - end tag for "meta" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

Tags: w3c-validation

I am getting an error as shown below

```
 Error Line 6, Column 467: end tag for "meta" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

 …ta,Manufacturing_Industrial,Educational_Training,Teacher,Engineering_Projects">

 ✉

 You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an     element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".
```

How can I solve this ?

Please see the source code of the page below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jobslamp-free online resume creation and sharing,fresher jobs,experienced   jobs,India jobs,Kerala jobs</title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="Karnataka,Bangalore_Rural,Healthcare,Office_Assistant,Kerala,Ernakulam,IT_Hardware_Networking,Engineer,Sales___Marketing,Executive,Maharashtra,Mumbai_City,Retailing,Manager,Kollam,CRM_CallCentres_BPO_ITES_Med.Trans,Customer_Care,Hotel_Travel_Tourism_Airlines_Hospitality,Front_Office_Staff,Andhra_Pradesh,Hyderabad,IT_Software,Java_Developer,Pathanamthitta,Manufacturing_Industrial,Educational_Training,Teacher,Engineering_Projects">
    <meta name="description" content="The best job oriented resume sharing system. Create and Publish your online resumes for FREE. Search and apply your dream jobs for FREE. Post your jobs for FREE.">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message points out the solution: replace the ending `>` with `/>`.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="all your keywords" />
```

You'll need to fix the other `meta` tags the same way.